# quick perl sigint handler

Tags: perl

What is the most convenient and clear way to handle program cleanup when receiving a Ctrl+C?

For example when my socket server gets killed this way, the TCP socket never gets closed. I would like a nice one liner I can put at the top of the program to set a sigint handler (or something like atexit) to close certain sockets (or doing any other kind of cleanup) before terminating the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to handle signals by assigning signal handlers via the [`%SIG`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG) hash. More details can be found at [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals).

Comment: a quick example: $SIG{INT}  = sub { print "oops" };

Answer (score 6):

Can't be quicker, more convenient or clearer than [sigtrap](http://p3rl.org/sigtrap).