# Can not bind to address because it is already in use

Tags: php, sockets

I have the following method:

```
    public static function listen(int $port, callable $callback) {
        ob_implicit_flush();

        if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
            println("socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
        }

        if (socket_bind($sock, '127.0.0.1', $port) === false) {
            println("socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)));
        }

        if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
            println("socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)));
        }

        if ($callback !== null && is_callable($callback)) {
            call_user_func($callback);
        }

        do {
            if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
                println("socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)));
                continue;
            }

            if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ))) {
                println("socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)));
                continue;
            }

            $eventName = trim(explode(' ', $buf)[1], '/');

            $msg = '';

            foreach (self::$events as $event) {
                if ($event->name() == $eventName) {
                    $msg = $event->headers();
                    $msg .= $event->run();
                    break;
                }
            }

            socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));
            socket_close($msgsock);
            println("socket closed");
        } while (true);

        socket_close($sock);

    }
```

When I run it through the commandline, it works fine. When I open a page in my browser and request content from the socket it outputs the right headers and displays the right content on the page.

When I edit the code, and press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and re-run the code, I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /path/to/file.php on line 20
socket_bind() failed: reason: Address already in use
```

This makes it hard to update code, as I have to wait a few moments until I can run the code again. Is there a way for me to close all the sockets when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>?

I noticed that I can start and stop the process lots times as long as I don't load it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but in general you need to register a handler for the signal SIGINT, and close any open resources in that handler.

Please note that if you register a handler for SIGINT, Ctrl-C will no longer terminate the process (it will instead trigger the handler), so the signal handler must make sure that the program terminates, if that is what you want.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864412/4402721%20answer) to [How do I catch a KILL or HUP or User Abort signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864349/how-do-i-catch-a-kill-or-hup-or-user-abort-signal), you should in PHP use [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) to register a signal had

**Edit:** Apparently, you must enable [ticks](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) for the signal handler to fire. A small example:

```
declare(ticks=1);

function sig_handler($signo)
{ 
     switch ($signo) {
         case SIGINT:
             echo "Caught SIGINT, exiting.\n";
             exit;
             break;
         default:
             // handle all other signals
             echo "Caught signal $signo...\n";
     }   

} 

// setup signal handler
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sig_handler');

for ($x = 0; $x <= 50; $x++) {
    echo "main loop: $x\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

The value for `ticks` is a trade-off between responsiveness and overhead.

Comment: I thought I needed to do that so I tried adding one but it isn't executing the callback. It stops the cancellation of keyboard input though. I put it right before the `do`.

Comment: regarding placement, I'd suggest installing the signal handler as early as possible.

Comment: I will give that a try when I get home.

Comment: I also had to use `socket_select()` because `socket_accept()` is blocking. where `socket_select()` is not.